# Unable to config django for mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to connect Django app to MySQL on windows 10. I have installed mysqlclient as an interface between my Django app and MySQL. Whenever I try to open dbshell I'm getting error something like this:-

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N, but settings are not configured 
You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Here is my setting.py file

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'blog',
    'USER':'root',
    'PASSWORD':'root',
    'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
    'PORT':'3306'
    }
}
```

I have tried other solutions on StackOverflow but it didn't work for me.
I also tried deleting the dbsqlite3 file from the project directory.
Versions for different elements are as follows:-

1. Python (3.6)
2. Django (1.11.4)
3. mysqlclient (1.3.12)
4. pip (9.0.1)
5. MySQL(5.7)

Comment: sounds like the error is somewhere else... can you run normally `manage.py shell` or `manage.py migrate` or `manage.py runserver`?

Comment: @efkin yes Everything else is working fine.

Comment: did you recently change your `manage.py` or your `models.py` or your `settings.py`?

Comment: This is my new project. I haven't written any code in it. I have tried on the older project but it didn't work. the only changes I have done is in settings.py file to write DATABASES configuration of MySQL.

Comment: @efkin I have edited my question and now posted my whole error. See if you can figure out something.

Comment: can you post your file structure please?

Comment: @efkin here is my file structure:- C:\Users\kiran\Documents\python\blog inside that blog folder and manage.py. Inside blog folder __pycache__ folder and __init__.py, settings.py, urls.py, wsgi.py

Comment: @efkin Is that fine?

Comment: how do you tell manage.py which settings to use?

Comment: can you try to execute `python manage.py --settings=blog.settings dbshell`

Comment: @efkin it is showing Unknown command: '--settings=blog.settings'

Comment: what about: `python manage.py dbshell --settings=blog.settings`

Comment: @efkin it showing another error. CommandError: You appear not to have the 'mysql' program installed or on your path.

Comment: but I have installed MySQL. I can open mysql shell and add create databases and all those things.

Comment: One more thing I have tried `pip3 install MySQL-python` but it was unsuccessful due to missing of some file in Microsoft visual studio 14.

Comment: @efkin I switched to Ubuntu and did the same things. Now if I run `python manage.py dbshell` it opens MySQL shell without any error. Thanks for your time though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved this problem. I was using `django-admin dbshell` command instead of `python manage.py dbshell`

In case of windows, set env variable for MySQL in user variables section, otherwise you will get CommandError saying that mysql is not installed.

For Ubuntu use `python3 manage.py dbshell`

Answer (score 0):

`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` variable is not available. run

```
python manage.py shell
```

if you linux user and run

```
python3 manage.py shell
```

as you use `python 3.6`

Comment: I did run that command. Opened python shell. Now what to do after that?

Comment: This will load the project's settings. now you can run again manage.py runserver or manage.py migrate. Let me know if it works

Comment: Actually, it is opening python shell. I can't see settings. I think I'm missing something here

Comment: press ctrl+c or exit the shell and run python manage.py migrate

Comment: Run that command. These are the result :- Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

Comment: python manage.py makemigrations and then python manage.py runserver .The previous problem solved :) Let me know

Comment: After running makemigrations. It is showing no changes are detected.

Comment: It is already written in question. I'm talking about this error django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N,

Comment: How to load project settings that you are talking about by opening python shell

Comment: import os

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

Comment: replace mysite to your project name

Comment: Are you sure about that syntax? It is giving me syntax error by pointing an arrow at "os.environ" part

Comment: I switched to Ubuntu and did the same thing. whenever I use python manage.py dbshell it opens the MySQL shell for that project by setting that module and everything works properly.